# Need Help Creating Excel Sorted Chart By Type

Tags: excel, sorting, graph, column-chart

I have data of the form

Type Car Hours Worked

I would like a column graph to show the type of car in each column, and the time worked on each car within that specific type. So for example, I would have 3 columns (coupe, sedan, convertible), and within each column I would have multiple sections showing each car within that type.

How would I do that?

thanks

Comment: Probably a `SUMIF()` statement would do the trick. Could you post a screenshot with some sample data that you're working with?

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/11253wl.jpg the columns are a little bit skewed because of how excel does things and I didn't change the cell type

Answer (score 2):

Try a PivotChart - it can summarize the results based on vehicle type in a column graph.